# Limitations of using "require user" multiple times in .htaccess in an Apache config?

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

Access to a Apache website can be controlled with a line as

```
Require user john paul george ringo
```

in a .htaccess file. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_user.html.
This same rule can also be written in multiple lines such as

```
Require user john 
Require user paul 
Require user george 
Require user ringo
```

My questions:

1. Is there any known limit on the number of usernames that can be included in a .htaccess file?
2. Does it make any difference using the single- versus multi-line approach?

Comment: Definitely don't hardcode 400+ names in an .htaccess file.  Instead of `Require user` look for a way to use `Require group`.  You might need to consider carefully what mechanism to use for representing groups.  I would personally hunt for a way to store this all in LDAP (or MS Active Directory) and build it into single sign on.